# How come Ser Loras can declare Sandor Clegane winner of the tourney

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In Season 1 episode 5 'The Wolf and the Lion' of 'Game of Thrones',  Sandor Clegane (Hound) saves Ser Loras Tyrell from Gregor Clegane (Mountain), when the Mountain attacks the  Ser Loras and fights him until King Robert stops both and Gregor Clegane  storms out in anger and Sandor bows to the king. Then Ser Loras declares him the winner of the Tourney.

It is understandable that Loras shows gratitude as he is in debt of Sandor but what right does he have to do so? There are other contestants also, why would they accept it? And I believe Sandor was not even participating.

Comment: I don't remember Loras saying he was winner of the whole *tourney* - I remember Renly and Baelish making some comments that implied there was prize money in this joust, which presumably Loras would be free and willing to share with Sandor (sharing it would boost his own reputation for gallantry and generosity), but I don't remember anything about the official title?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the book, this fight between Ser Loras and the Mountain was semifinal, and in the other semifinal the Hound has already defeated Jamie Lannister. The Hound is supposed to face Ser Loras in the final tilt, but Loras, in gratitude to the Hound for saving his life, yields the match.

The screenwriters of the show have ignored a lot of details from the book, some details they have changed, especially in the last season, but this scene just had to be entered into the show, because I think it is a crucial moment to start getting to know the true Sandor Clegane.

Comment: In the book the tourney is a lot bigger and introduces other characters as well, that are not mentioned in the series until later. (Making it possible to cast the actors only for later seasons and/or avoiding more recasts).

Comment: I don't think it's fair to say the writers ignored details from the book. I find it much more likely that they made careful decisions as to which details to include and which to cut. If budget (including expected revenue) was no object and they had cooperating actors, I'm sure they would have loved to be more expressive with the decisions they made. But at the end of the day, they have to cram 800 pages into 540 minutes of tape. No easy task.

Comment: @corsiKa I agree with you to some extent. Before I started to watch show, I read the books, and I was satisfied how they managed to bring the story to the screen. I was aware that they couldn't completely follow the story on the screen. It's just too many characters, too many details... But in the last season they went too far with all that changes, and spoiled the reading of the following book. GOT is still great show, but I would recommend everyone to also read the books.

Comment: @IvanaMNE Agreed.  The books actually explain a lot of the Game of Thrones questions on this site.  I know the questions are about the show and not the books, but some questions about the show simply cannot be answered unless you are a writer on the show.  However, the books fill in a lot of "gaps" from the show.